# Building Qt static, can't find MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, qt, powershell, mingw

I'm trying to build a static version of Qt, so I could make a .exe file of my project.

I have found [this](http://wiki.qt.io/How-to-build-a-static-Qt-for-Windows-MinGW) tutorial, and am using the script made by the tutorial author. When I try to run the script, my PowerShell gives me this>

```
Building static Qt version 5.3.1
ERROR: MinGW environment not found, no Qt prebuilt version?
Press Enter to continue...:
```

This is impossible. I know this because I already had made projects with Qt5 and built them with my MinGW compiler.

Some additional info:
MinGW is located:

```
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32 (/bin/gcc.exe)
```

When I open the script, theres this line>

```
#Search all instances of gcc.exe from C:\Qt prebuilt environment. 
$GccList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Qt\*\Tools\mingw*\bin\gcc.exe | ForEach-Object FullName | Sort-Object)
```

So, to me it looks like the gcc should be found by the script.

Anyone have any ideas as to what is happening here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the answer to your question but probably the solution for your problem.

There is no need to make Qt static for creating an executable of your sources. The static option is more appropriate for embedded system without OS, or with a very thin OS below. I can't imagine, it would make sense on windows.

Build a release version, copy your exe and all required dlls of Qt and mingw to one directory and copy this directory to any windows pc. It should work.

For checking, which dlls are required, use [depends-tool](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

For providing your exe in a more professional way, create an installer. I'd recommend [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which is very easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, managed to do that, but now, after copying all the dlls my project is dependent on, my project is> ~130 Kb .exe file and ~44 MB of different .dll files.
Is there a way to know what part of which .dll my project is using, so I can edit some of them, thus making the project smaller?

Comment: You don't need to include all DLLs from Windows and system directories. Only Qt and Mingw should be enough. Begin with Qt5Gui, Qt5Core, libwinpthread, libstdc++-6, libgcc and add missing DLLs one after another. Actually, 44 MB is nothing unusual on a Windows PC. Your project is so small, because all functionality is in DLLs.

Answer (score 4):

Replace
`C:\Qt\*\Tools\mingw*\bin\gcc.exe`
with
`C:\Qt\Tools\mingw*\bin\gcc.exe`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to copy the dlls use windeployqt, its very simple than using dependency walker. This will copy all the dlls for you to a given folder...

```
Copy <MyApp.exe> to a folder say <MyAppPackage>

cd to <MyAppPackage>

C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\windeployqt.exe MyApp.exe
```

All the dlls will be copied to `<MyAppPackage>` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

The path that reads " C:\Qt*\Tools\mingw*\bin\gcc.exe" needed to be changed to " C:\Qt\Tools\mingw*\bin\gcc.exe" on my (Windows 10) system.

https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW